# What are the possible reasons a kernel security update would fail to occur during unattended-upgrades?

Tags: security, unattended-upgrades

I have setup unattended-upgrades along the lines of the Ubuntu [AutomaticSecurityUpdates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package) doc. However, it had not updated to the latest Linux kernel, which was definitely a "security" update. What are the possible reasons?

I ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` manually today, and that upgraded the kernel successfully.

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};

// List of packages to not update (regexp are supported)
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "05:00";
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your /boot partition is out of space for the new kernel, it will fail. An `apt-get autoremove'`usually clears it up unless you have a kernel stuck 1/2 way through an install. In that case you need to manually make room and run `apt-get -f install` to complete the install.

I wonder if in your situation you didn't have a kernel stuck installing and perhaps cleaned up some space in your process. I think I've seen that once, it isn't common. Usually it just breaks so congrats!